# VBA SQL Join Query

Tags: sql, vba, join

I am having troubles with a VBA SQL JOIN. I Keep Getting A "Join Expression Not Supported" Error. The Following Code Works In The Query Design View but seems to throw an error when in vba.

```
Dim Rs As DAO.RecordSet

Set Rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset( _
        "SELECT Schools.ID, Schools.[School Name],Schools.Address, Schools.Postcode, Schools.[Principal name], " & _
        "Schools.[E-Mail], Schools.Phone, Schools.Region, Schools.JTHE, Schools.[Social Status], Events.Program " & _
        "FROM Schools INNER JOIN Events ON Schools.ID = Events.School WHERE ((Schools.Region = '" & RegionOne & _
        "' Or Schools.Region = '" & RegionTwo "' Or Schools.Region = '" & RegionThree "' Or Schools.Region = '" & _ 
        RegionFour "') AND (Schools.JTHE = " & JTHE1 & " Or Schools.JTHE = " & JTHE2 ") AND (Schools.[Social Status] = '" & _ 
        StatusBox.Value "') AND (Events.Program = '" & ProgramBox.Value & "'));")
```

This Similar Query Works

```
Set Rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Schools WHERE " & _
        "(((Schools.Region)='" & RegionOne & _
        "' Or (Schools.Region)='" & RegionTwo & _
        "' Or (Schools.Region)='" & RegionThree & _
        "' Or (Schools.Region)='" & RegionFour & _
        "') AND ((Schools.[Social Status])='" & StatusBox.Value & _
        "') AND ((Schools.JTHE)=" & JTHE1 & " Or (Schools.JTHE)=" & JTHE2 & "));")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is your declaration for `RegionOne`, `RegionTwo`, `RegionThree`, `RegionFour`, `JTHE1`, `JTHE2`?

Comment: At The Top Of The Module. The Are Initialized As Strings   
    Dim RegionOne As String
    Dim RegionTwo As String
    Dim RegionThree As String
    Dim RegionFour As String
    Dim JTHE1 As Boolean
    Dim JTHE2 As Boolean

Comment: Try a **Debug.Print**, see what you get int he generated SQL in the immediate window. Then copy the generated SQL into the Query window, you might be able to lock on the error a bit precisely. If not, try one condition at a time. Try using just the region first, then the JTHE, then Program.

Comment: Found Part of the problem. ProgramBox.Value was returning the ID not the Value. ThisNow allows me to extract the information from the recordset and place it into a textbox on the form. however I still get the same error when using     DoCmd.OpenReport "All Schools", acViewPreview

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why is that. It is hard to spot error when your doing it on VBA, unlike if your in an actual SQL Management studio where you can spot the lines that errors out. Nonetheless, you may try this:

```
Set Rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset( _
    "SELECT Schools.ID, Schools.[School Name], Schools.Address, " & _
        "Schools.Postcode, Schools.[Principal name], Schools.[E-Mail], " & _
        "Schools.Phone, Schools.Region, Schools.JTHE, Schools.[Social Status], " & _
        "Events.Program " & _
    "FROM Schools " & _
    "INNER JOIN Events " & _
        "ON Schools.ID = Events.School " & _
    "WHERE Schools.Region IN (" & _
        "'" & RegionOne & "'," & _
        "'" & RegionTwo & "'," & _
        "'" & RegionThree & "'," & _
        "'" & RegionFour & "') " & _
    "AND Schools.JTHE IN (" & JTHE1 & ", " & JTHE2 & ") " & _
    "AND Schools.[Social Status]='" & StatusBox.Value & "' " & _
    "AND Events.Program='" & ProgramBox.Value & "';")
```

I formatted it as such to give you the story of the query (and that is how I will write it in SQL). 
 Not really a direct to the point answer to your question but I just simplified your `OR` statements and instead uses `IN`. 
 You might get a:

> Too many continuous line error

So adjust the concatenation of strings. I have not tested this of course (although it compiles) but my goal is to give you idea on a possible way to do it. HTH.